# Will this function make the strSerial always unique?

Tags: php, sql-server

Will this function make the `strSerial` of an item always unique or it only gets date time and if someone execute the script at the same time, they will get both same `strSerial` ?

```
  $x = explode(' ', microtime());
  $nSerialLo = ($x[0] . date('s') . date('i') + date('H')) . rand(0, 1024);
  $nSerialHi = (date('d') . date('m') . (date('Y') % 100)) . rand(0, 1024);
  $nSerial = $pEquipped->ToUInt64($nSerialHi, $nSerialLo);
  $pItem->SetNum($nItemID)->SetSerial($nSerial)->SetDurability($nDurability)->SetCount(1);
```

Comment: By `strSerial` do you mean `$nSerial`?

Comment: Yes, strSerial is to make the item in the game unique, so the dupe scanner won't delete it. (All items should have unique strserial otherwise it will be counted as duped item (illegal))

Comment: at the moment its unique but sometimes its not ... and why is that ? Sometimes we end to have 2 different items with same strSerial when they should have unique. I believe they were obtained at same date time because I see thats what the script get date time ?

Comment: so, use Microseconds, check "date("Y/m/d H:i:s"). substr((string)microtime(), 1, 6);"

Comment: Can you please remake it for me because it something really important and if i screw it up .. I'll be lost really. I will be so much grateful.

Comment: Why is this question tagged with sql-server? It doesn't appear to have anything to do with that?

Comment: no, it's not guaranteed unique. you have a non-zero probability of generating the SAME random number for two or more users if they hit the script on the same time. Not very likely, but also **NOT** impossible.

Answer (score 0):

These are your variables:

```
  $nSerialLo = ($x[0] . date('s') . date('i') + date('H')) . rand(0, 1024);
  $nSerialHi = (date('d') . date('m') . (date('Y') % 100)) . rand(0, 1024);
echo  $nSerialLo."<br>";
echo $nSerialHi."<br>";
```

its return:

```
4930701
140613904
```

i added microtime:

```
$date_micro= date("YmdHis").substr((string)microtime(), 1, 6);
$removedote=explode('.',$date_micro); 
$new_date= $removedote[0].$removedote[1];
echo $new_date."<br>";
```

its return:

```
2013061415154969409
```

With microtime, i think it will be a unique number

EDIT:

what about now?

```
$x = explode(' ', microtime());
  $y = explode(' ', microtime());
  $new_val=$y[0] * $x[0];
  $nSerialLo = ($new_val . date('s') . date('i') + date('H')) * rand(0, 1024);
  $z = explode('.', $nSerialLo);
  $nSerialHi = ($z[1] .$x[0] . (idate('U') % $x[1])) . rand(0, 1024);
  echo  $nSerialLo."<br>";
  echo $nSerialHi."<br>";
```

Comment: thanks but I think I've got at the moment `$x = explode(' ', microtime());` ??? So, I've got microtime ?

Comment: so, what I should do now ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add microseconds like this:

```
$nSerialLo = ($x[0] . date('u') . date('s') . date('i') + date('H')) . rand(0, 1024);
```

However, this don't guarantee that you will not get clashes with your serials, so I recommend you to store your serials in a database and check if it was created before.